# Negative binomial distribution with non integer parameter

Tags: probability-distributions, actuarial-science

I am solving an actuarial math problem.

Suppose that the number of claims, $N$, in a year follows a Poisson distribution $\mathrm{Po}(\Theta)$, where $\Theta$ is a gamma distribution $\Gamma(5, 1/2)$, and its probability density function (pdf) is given by $\frac{(1/2)^5}{\Gamma(5)}x^4\mathrm{e}^{-x/2}$.

In the next year, there is an expected 10% decrease in contracts. The problem is to find the distribution of $N$ for the next year.

Here is what I did. Initially, without considering the 10% decrease,$N$ follows a negative binomial distribution $\mathrm{NB}(5, 1/3)$. However, I got stuck at this point.

The solution suggests that due to the 10 % decrease in contracts, $N$ will follow $\mathrm{NB}(5*0.9, 1/3)$. I have not encountered this computation before and based on my understanding, the interpretation of $\mathrm{NB}(a, p)$ is the number of failure $a$ before a successful trial with probability $p$. Consequently, I assumed the parameter $a$ cannot take non-integer values.

My question is: Is this solution correct? If so, what is the interpretation of it? Additionally, what is the probability density function (pdf) associated with this distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the marginal distribution of $N$ is correct.  The hierarchical model is
$$N \mid \Theta \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\Theta), \\ \Theta \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(5, 1/2),$$
hence
$$N \sim \operatorname{NegativeBinomial}(5, 1/3)$$
with parametrization
$$\Pr[N = n] = \binom{n+4}{4} (1/3)^5 (2/3)^n, \quad n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}.$$

It is worth noting that in the negative binomial PMF with general parameters $r$ and $p$
$$\Pr[N = n] = \binom{n+r-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^n, \quad n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \},$$
we can write the binomial coefficient as
$$\binom{n+r-1}{r-1} = \frac{(n+r-1)!}{(r-1)! \, n!} = \frac{(r)(r+1)(r+2)\cdots(r+n-1)}{n!} = \prod_{j=1}^n \frac{j+r-1}{j}.$$
And this product does not require $r$ to be an integer.  So for instance, the choice $n = 3, r = 7/3$ yields $$\binom{13/3}{4/3} = \prod_{j=1}^3 \frac{j+4/3}{j} = \frac{455}{81}.$$
Consequently, [the parameter $r$ can be any positive real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

That said, I take issue with the claim that $10\%$ decrease in contracts implies that $$N_{\text{new}} \sim \operatorname{NegativeBinomial}(4.5, 1/3).$$  There is no reason to believe that the reduced frequency manifests through a change in the parameter $r$ only.  The expectation of a negative binomial distribution is
$$\operatorname{E}[N] = \frac{r(1-p)}{p},$$
and we could certainly obtain a $10\%$ decrease in the expected number of contracts by adjusting $p$ instead of $r$, or even $r$ and $p$ simultaneously.  For instance, $\operatorname{E}[N] = 10$, so next year, we expect $\operatorname{E}[N_{\text{new}}] = 0.9(10) = 9$.  But this could be achieved by choosing $r = 5$, $p = \frac{5}{14}$.  The question doesn't adequately specify how the probability distribution of $N_{\text{new}}$ is modified.  One possible way that the question could have uniquely identified the parameters is if it said that there is an expected $10\%$ decrease in contracts but the variance of the number of contracts next year will remain the same, in which case the solution requires $r = \frac{27}{7}$ and $p = \frac{3}{10}$; the proof of which I leave to you as an exercise.